# Threads waiting in Monitor.Wait are actually waiting to re-acquire a lock which they released

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have error  "[Report](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hj2tx3jbxh4nvj0/errorReport.html)"

what I was trying is:
I have very long list of Users and need to send mail and do other task.
So I want to do that with some time interval without main process being disturbed.

So I did like:

```
new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    foreach (var invitedUser in invitations)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(100, 1500));
                        new EmailHelper().SendEmailToInvitedUser(fromUser, invitedUser, content);
                    }
                }).Start();
```

but error is like on above report.
What am I doing wrong and what might be solution?